# Scala: Read variables defined in shell script

Tags: scala, process, processbuilder

From within my Scala application, I want to execute a script (e.g. setenv.sh) which sets some variables. I then want to read back these variables in my application to do some further processing. Here is my sample setenv.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=0000
```

I have the following but it doesn't work. I tried many alternatives but failed to do it.

```
Seq("bash", "-c", "source setenv.sh && env").!!
```

The above command still gives me the old environment variables and i cannot see TEST.

My goal is to just load all the variables in setenv.sh file and use them in my application.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't work that easy. Keep in mind that you are opening a *new* shell process. That process sees the setting - to then end.

If at all try explicitly exporting that value.

Alternatively you could print the values to stdout and have Scala parse that output.

Comment: I am currently looking for a solution without any modifications to setenv.sh script. Is it possible to execute the setenv.sh and then somehow get the environment variables of the new process in the parent process?

Comment: Again: currently your script isn't doing something that has any effect on the parent process. Unless you change the script, you are broken.